# "vh" and "vw" not relative to screen height

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

So I have a div (white box), then inside that I have a second div (red box) and inside that I have multiple smaller divs (purple box):
[image]

Now in the CSS for the purple box, I set the height to be 10vh. However when I add more purple boxes, each box squeezes and the height decreases. I'm 99% sure the problem comes from the fact that I'm using a flex box for the red box. How can I get vh/vw to work normally, where its based on the user's screen size? Here is my code for all the divs:

White Div:

```
.whiteDiv{
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  border-radius: 30px;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 70vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

redDiv:

```
.topSectionHistory {
  width: 30vw;
  height: 50vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  overflow: scroll;
  background-color: red;
}
```

purpleDiv:

```
.purpleDiv{
  border-radius: 30px;
  width: 25vw;
  height: 10vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #5f72be, #9921e8);
}
```

How can I use vh/vw for the purple boxes, so that it doesn't resize?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] with your HTML mark up, It will make it easier for us to help you

Comment: I mean I provided the code for each div. The HTML is just nesting each div, which shouldnt be too complex. Therefore I believe the code I provided is enough.

Comment: By providing a [mcve], you make it easier for us to help you. We can focus on the problem and not have to construct something to test, that should be up to you. Don't make us guess and make assumptions with your HTML, provide it. The more effort you put in to your question, the more likely you are to get help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it by setting 'min-height'.

```css
.whiteDiv {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    border-radius: 30px;
    width: 30vw;
    height: 70vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.topSectionHistory {
    width: 30vw;
    height: 50vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    overflow-Y: scroll;
    background-color: red;
}

.purpleDiv {
    border-radius: 30px;
    width: 25vw;
    height: 10vh;
    min-height: 10vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: white;
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #5f72be, #9921e8);
}
```

```html
<div class="whiteDiv">
    <div class="topSectionHistory">
        <div class="purpleDiv"></div>
        <div class="purpleDiv"></div>
        <div class="purpleDiv"></div>
        <div class="purpleDiv"></div>
        <div class="purpleDiv"></div>
        <div class="purpleDiv"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome this works! Thanks